# Uno Platform : Designs not displaying

Tags: visual-studio-2019, uwp-xaml, windows-update, uno, webassembly

I am unable to view the designs of my code. Getting this message.

> Visual Studio requires a newer version of Windows to display this
> content.  Please update to Windows 10,version 2004(10.0.19041.0) or
> later.

I am currently running on Windows version 1909 and Visual Studio (Version 16.7.2)
There are no current windows updates available currently for my device.

[image: Visual Studio Warning here]

Any insights to this will be valuable.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Well, the message is quite self-explanatory.

This functionality requires Windows 10 version 2004, whereas your system is currently at 1909. You won't be able to see the design view until you get the Windows update.

Hopefully [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4028685/windows-10-get-the-update) can help you update your Windows version.